# syntax error on case statement after ssh session

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bourne-shell

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter the raspberry ip address you want to connect:"
read Rasp_id

sshpass -p "the@Donut" ssh -t -X -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@$Rasp_id << E2
        echo -e "Enter the case you want to echo\n 1.1 a \n 2.1 b"
        read option
        case "\$option" in
        1)
        echo "a"
        ;;

        2)
        echo "b"
        ;;
esac
E2
```

I'm writing a script that start a ssh session and then perform some modifications on remote machine, it will give syntax error as follow:

```
bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: line 3: `        1)'
```

Comment: https://shellcheck.net

Comment: thank you Panki, i have pasted in shellcheck.net and after apply fix it still gives the same error as before.

Comment: Post your best code here. Not the old one.

Comment: thanks you so much !

Comment: You may have a `chellcheck` command on your system. It is part of Debian (and probably others).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are mixing what you are using stdin for, providing a program to be executed on the remote machine and input for that program.

As written the following happens.

- remote shell reads `echo -e "Enter the case you want to echo\n 1.1 a \n 2.1 b"` from stdin and does the echo.
- remote shell reads `read option` from stdin and does the read.
- The `read` reads `case "\$option" in` from stdin and sets option to this.
- The remote shell gets `1)` from stdin and gives you a syntax error.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, my intention is to take stdin from read and use it in the case statement. do you mind elaborate more on the syntax error. sorry for the troubles..

Comment: Does my edited answer help or do you need more help? The reason `1)` is a syntax error is because it is not in a case statement. There are only a few places that `)` is syntactically correct and this is not one of them.

Comment: i see, i might need more help as i can see from tutorials case statement is always the format of                                                                                                                   case "$1" in

1)

Comment: The point is that the remote shell never executes the `case` command. That line of input is eaten by the `read`. The remote shell sees the `echo`, the `read` and the `1)`.

Comment: thank you for the help. I might need to use other conditional statement then other than case statement inside the ssh session.

Comment: No, you need to rethink how you are going to provide the program to be executed on the remote machine. For example you might do the `read`  (and probably the `echo`) on the local machine before doing the ssh, and just do the `case` on the remote machine. This assumes that the things you want to do on the remote machine don't need to read from stdin. Otherwise you probably need to pass the program as a command line argument rather than as a "here" document so stdin is still available.

Answer (score 2):

Here, to complement @icarus' answer, you could write it:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  printf >&2 'Enter the raspberry ip address you want to connect to: '
  IFS= read -r ip
  set -- "$ip"
fi

for ip do
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "Connecting to $ip"
  SSHPASS=the@Donut sshpass -e \
    ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "pi@$ip" "$(cat << 'EOF'

    printf >&2 '%s\n' 'Enter the case you want to echo' \
                      ' 1.1 a' \
                      ' 2.1 b'
    IFS= read -r option
    case "$option" in
      (1) echo a;;
      (2) echo b;;
    esac
EOF
)"
done
```

That is:

- avoid `echo` (`echo -n` / `echo -e` are not standard sh+utilities syntax)
- avoid `read`'s default post-processing and read a line of input raw.
- allow the user to pass the hostname(s) as argument which makes for scripts easier to automate.
- issue prompts and other things that are not the actual *output* of the script on stderr (again so it can be automated and you can do things like `actual_output=$(that-script)` for instance).
- avoid passing a password on the command line as that's public. Since that script contains sensitive information, you'll want to tighten access permissions to it so that password is only exposed to users who need access to it.
- the script is passed as an argument to `ssh` instead of its stdin, so that script can still query the user via stdin.
- that's done by capturing the output of `cat` which is fed a here-document whose terminator (`EOF`) has been quoted, so no expansion is done in the here document.
- removed the unnecessary X11 forwarding here as there's no command in there that needs to connect to a X server.
- also removed the pseudo-tty as nothing in that script requires it.
- added a few missing quotes.

The above assumes the login shell of the `pi` user at `$ip` is POSIX-sh-like.

Comment: +1 for passing the script as an argument rather than on stdin, which is the basic problem the OP has.